# Tapestry 5 : Multi selection in a dropdown menu

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, multi-select, tapestry

In my tapestry 5.3 project, I use a form to gather some parameters.
One of the parameters is a dropdown-list. I want to enable multi-selection of the items in the dropdown. Hence, the user could select more than one entry from the dropdown before submitting the parameters entered.

I already tried to implement the example in the tapestry wiki (here[1](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5MultipleSelectOnObjects)), but in vain. It is causing some Java errors during compilation. The methods used in the example do not exist in the tapestry jars I use.

Anyway, I'm stuck with this since weeks. I would be very thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Please, add some code, error messages, you know...

Answer (score 3):

Select doesn't support multiple choices, use [checklist](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Checklist.html) or [pallette](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Palette.html) instead.

Or you could roll-your-own `multiselect` component which is a `select` element that supports multiple selections (backed by a collection). You'll likely extend [AbstractField](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/base/AbstractField.html) to accomplish this.